# I want to insert some element to specific index of empty list

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I have s empty array. For example: `base=[]`. Then i want to insert `"Tofiq"`string to 3 th element. If i use `print(base[3])` it must return`"Tofiq"` string. Please help me about it!

Comment: But the list is empty. It doesn't have a third element. Even if you could set it, what would go in el 1 and 2?

Comment: Define the list of say 4 or more elements first e.g `base = ['' for _ in range(4]`, then you can do `base[3] = 'Tofiq'`

Comment: Proper way of handling the case is to use a dictionary, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to add intermediate elements to the list or use a dictionary instead of a list.

```
 base   = []     
 index  = 3
 base  += [None]*(index-len(base)+1)
 base[index] = "ToFig"
```

or

```
 base    = dict()
 base[3] = "ToFig"
```

Comment: First example is not working. But, second example is not useful for my situacion

Comment: My bad, I inverted the subtraction. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

list cannot have empty nodes, hence fill the list till the required index or use dictionary

Comment: This answer sounds more like a comment. Once you have accumulated sufficient reputation, you will be allowed to comment everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign 'Tofiq' to index 3 of the empty list (for example, `base[3] = 'Tofiq'`), it will give IndexError. You should initialize your list instead of creating an empty list.